# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I have coded a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu in the static site proof. The client wants sub-menus and I have that working. I have made the menus in Wordpress but now the sub-menus are not working. Here is the html:

```
<!-- Main navbar ================================================== -->
<!--     <div class="row"> -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default main-navbar" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header main-nav">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div><!-- .navbar-header -->


          <div id="navbar"class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who We Are<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="who.html">Our Story</a></li>

                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Our Team</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bod.html">Board Members</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sports<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Olympic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Paralympic</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Athletes and Coaches<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Athletes</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="current.html">Current</a></li>
                        <li><a href="alumni.html">Alumni</a></li>
                        <li><a href="nextgen.html">NEXTGEN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="up-coming.html">Up and Coming</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="coaches.html">Coaches</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Training Groups</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="curling.html">Curling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="diving.html">Diving</a></li>
                        <li><a href="seniorWomenVolley.html">Senior Women's Volleyball</a></li>
                        <li><a href="seniorWomenBasket.html">Senior Women's Wheelchair Basketball</a></li>
                        <li><a href="wesmenWrestling.html">Wesmen Wrestling</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Partnerships<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="landscape-sport-canada.html">Sport Canada</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-owp.html">Own the Podium</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-sport-mb.html">Sport Manitoba</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-copsin.html">COPSIN</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-coaching-assoc.html">Coaching Association of Canada</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-national-coach.html">National Coaching Institute</a></li>
                  <li><a href="landscape-corp-community.html">Corporate Community</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service Delivery<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="delivery-ist.html">IST</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sport Science</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="delivery-dietetics.html">Sport Dietetics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="delivery-psychology.html">Sport Psychology</a></li>
                        <li><a href="delivery-physiology.html">Physiology</a></li>
                        <li><a href="delivery-condition.html">Strength and Conditioning</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sport Medicine</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Life Services</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="gamePlan.html">Game Plan</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="elegibility.html">Elegibility</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">What’s Happening<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Calendar of Events</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="externalEvents.html">External</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cscmEvents.html">CSCM</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">In The News</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="latestNews.html">Latest News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pressrelease.html">Press Releases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://cscm.ca/" target="_blank">Archive</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Community Involvement</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <li><a href="impact.html">IMPACT Camps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sportArtProgram.html">Sports and Arts Program</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Event Sign-up & Registration</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div><!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->


        </div><!-- container -->
        </div>
  </nav><!-- .navbar navbar-default main-nav -->
```

The CSS is:

```
#header {
  z-index: 99999;
}


#navbar {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-family: $sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:$text-color;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.container-fluid {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.nav > li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
.navbar-default {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #d1d1d1;
}
.main-nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: #d1d1d1;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.main-nav li a {
  font-family: $sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:$text-color;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.main-nav .nav {
  float: none;
}
.main-nav .nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
/*  margin: 0 5px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*.main-nav .nav li a {
  color:$text-color;
  width: 100%;
}*/
.main-nav .nav li a:hover {
  color: #a31c27;
}
.main-nav .nav a {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  color: $reversed-color;
}

.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  font-family: $sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.dropdown-submenu > li > a:focus, 
.dropdown-submenu > li > a:hover {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position:relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top:0;left:100%;
  margin-top:-6px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display:block;
  background: #d1d1d1;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display:block;content:" ";
  float:right;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-color:transparent;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: $text-color;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:-12px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: $primaryColor;
    background-color: $background;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: none;
}
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: static;
}
.dropdown-menu li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
visibility: visible;
display: block;
top: 0px;
left: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu a:after {
  display:block;content:" ";
  float:right;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-color:transparent;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: $text-color;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:-12px;
}
```

If someone can give me a hand that would be great.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Is your this code working without wordpress?

Comment: I can get the dropdowns to work on iPhone and on Desktop but can't get the multi-level dropdowns to work on Android. When I click the menubar I get the dropdown but when clicking the sub-menu it closes and jumps to the top of the screen.